# How can we initialize new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(Input, Options); for two text boxes in same page?

Tags: autocomplete, textbox, multiple-instances

How can we intialize new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(Input, Options); for two text boxes in same page?
 When i am trying to do that the first initialized is working and the second one is not working....

Alaready i have tried google.maps.event.removeListener(autocomplete); and google.maps.event.clearListeners(autocomplete, 'place_changed'); methods to unbind the first one..but nothing worked out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is the most elegant, but this worked for me...

```js
// add autocomplete functionality to our search fields
var input_one = document.getElementById('input_one');
var input_two = document.getElementById('input_two');
var autocomplete_one = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_one);
var autocomplete_two = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_two);

// listeners to capture updated location
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete_one, 'place_changed', function() {
  var objLocation = autocomplete_one.getPlace();
  autoComplete_Update(objLocation);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete_two , 'place_changed', function() {
  var objLocation = autocomplete_two.getPlace();
  autoComplete_Update(objLocation);
});

function autoComplete_Update( objLocation ) {
  // handle results from either autocomplete here.
  // you could obviously have two handler functions, 
  // or pass in extra parameters if you wanted to differentiate between the two
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Only the first one I click on works, doesn't matter which one I click on first though.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 3):

This is a more elegant way of what Noizy answered.

Put the creation of the autocomplete and the creation of the listener in a seperate function so you can reuse it.

I've added some logging in this code so you can see the result in the console.

### Code

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="search-area">
        <label for="search-field-from">From</label><input type="textbox" id="search-field-from" />
        <label for="search-field-to">To</label><input type="textbox" id="search-field-to" />
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var place_from;
        var place_to;

        function initialize() {
            initializeMap();
            initializeAutocomplete('from');
            initializeAutocomplete('to');
        }

        function initializeMap() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.85, 4.35);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);
        }

        function initializeAutocomplete(type) {
            var input = document.getElementById('search-field-' + type);
            input.value = ''; //clear autocomplete input field

            var countrySelector = document.getElementById('country-selector');
            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)']
            };
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

            addAutompleteListener(autocomplete, type);
        }

        function addAutompleteListener(autocomplete, type) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                if ((typeof place.geometry != "undefined")) {
                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17);
                    }

                    eval('place_' + type + ' = place');

                    console.log('You just filled in the "' + type + '" location');
                    console.log(eval('place_' + type));
                    //console.log(place_to);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
body {padding:10px;font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;}
#map-canvas{width:100%; height:90%;}
#search-area{padding:20px;margin-bottom:20px;background:#ddd;text-align:center;}
input{font-size:20px;padding:5px;border:0;width:500px;}
label{font-size:20px; padding:10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed this for a project, this is what I used (in CoffeeScript), it worked perfectly.

```
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("ac_places")
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input) for input in inputs
```

The text boxes' class was 'ac_places'.